# Responsive background image size that scale different devices and resolutions

Tags: css, media-queries

We want a background image for a webpage that scales to fit different devices sizes(like iphone,ipad,desktops,laptops) and with different desktop/laptop resolutions?

What the possible combinations of the image background we have to create and at what height and width in px those has to be?

Note:We are using CSS3 media queries to render them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `background-size:cover`

eg :

```
div{
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe edge or just bootstrap, it's included in the packet